# npm peer dependency fails for styled-components and react @16.0.0-beta.5

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, styled-components

I have installed the latest styled-components (@2.2.1).

I also have react @16.0.0-beta.5 installed.

styled-components has the following peer dependency for react:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">= 0.14.0 < 17.0.0-0"
  },
```

I am getting the following warning:

**styled-components@2.2.1 requires a peer of react@>= 0.14.0 < 17.0.0-0 but none was installed.**

But surely react @16.0.0-beta.5 is less than react@17.0.0-0?

I can get rid of the warning by changing the peer dependency to this:

```
"react": ">= 0.14.0"
```

...and anyway, it is only a warning. But I would love to understand why "< 17.0.0-0" somehow rules out @16.0.0-beta.5?

Is it because whatever parses the versions can't cope with the non-numeric characters in "beta"?

Answer (score 0):

After installing styled-components

```
   react-native-safe-area-context@0.7.3
```

This Should Work